# Is there an easier way to find the index of the first letter in a string?

Tags: c#

I have a function that returns the index of the first alphabet letter found in a string, or -1 if no letter is found.  It seems like there should be a way to do this with extension methods instead of looping, but I can't think of one:

```
int findFirstLetter(string str)
{
 for(int ctr=0;ctr<str.Length;ctr++)
 {
  if (Char.IsLetter(str[ctr]))
  {
   return ctr;
  }
 }
 return -1;
}
```

Comment: return str.ToList().FindIndex(c => Char.IsLetter(c));

Comment: I'd like to vote-to-close this question, if you don't mind: it's more of a "code golf" question than a code review.

Comment: @ChrisW, does that mean I should post questions like this to Code Golf?

Comment: I don't know but I don't think it's on-topic there: it's not a puzzle or game. Perhaps it is on-topic here, I don't know: http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/711/34757 suggests "no" but http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/1583/34757 suggests "yes".

Comment: One problem with this question is that it's hard to make a valid answer except as a comment (because an answer which only contains code isn't usually a code review of the code in the OP). And you're "asking for code to be written" which is also off-topic here.

Comment: Looking at the top answer on http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/943/do-we-need-to-revisit-code-golf-questions also suggests that my question is on-topic for Code Review.  I think Code Golf is more specifically about character count; I just want to find an efficient solution.  I'm not asking for code to be written; if you'd responded, "Try using `ToList()`," that would be a good hint to get me going.  I'd be happy to ask about it in Meta, if you'd like to get a more definitive answer from the community.

Comment: You're welcome to ask about it in Meta; and/or see how other people vote on this question; and/or see whether they answer (if it isn't closed), or comment.

Comment: I would guess that my solution is probably **not** efficient (because of the `ToList()`): it's only, a more compact source code.

Comment: [Meta discussion here](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/1601/does-this-question-belong-on-code-review-should-it-go-to-code-golf), if you're interested.

Comment: A trick such as @ChrisW 's first comment likely doesn't even eliminate the loop.  It just hides it, but a "FindIndex" method in any language almost certainly uses a loop in its implementation.  Arguably though, ChrisW's comment is actually worse because even given equivalent efficiency, his answer is far less readable than what is posted in the question.

Comment: @nhgrif - I think readability is subjective.  If you are new to Linq ChrisW's solution is a little mind boggling.  But after spending time with Linq, you start to "think in Linq." I actually find his answer far more readable: take a string, make a list out of it, find the index of something in that list, that something is a letter.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have no issue with the loop. It is about as fast as it can be. I would recommend renaming the method to match the other IndexOf methods.... something like `IndexOfAlphaChar`.

There is no reason to worry about this code. Move on to bigger problems.

Comment: Maybe nitpicking but I do have an issue with the loop! It could be about 25% faster by storing `str.Length` in a temporary variable `strLen` and then using this in the loop condition `ctr<strLen`. No need to keep re-evaluating `str.Length` if the string length never changes.

Answer (score 6):

I think that the biggest problem with the code you posted is not the structure, but variable naming and other stylistic issues:

1. It took me a while to realize what `ctr` meant (control?). Don't shorten variable names like this, write them in full if you can.
2. Opinions about the right indentation style vary wildly, but I think that one space is too little. The common values are 2 or 4 spaces or a single tab (`\t`).
3. Use spaces more often to make the structure of your code clearer:

   ```
   for (int ctr = 0; ctr < str.Length; ctr++)
   ```
4. For types that can be written as a keyword, I always write them that way. That means I would write `char.IsLetter` (lowercase `c`).

Comment: I agree with you about the tabs and spacing; when I use Ctrl+K,D in Visual Studio, the text gets formatted in accordance with your suggestions.  With regard to `Char.IsLetter`, `Char` is a primitive in C# that has a static method `IsLetter`.  So it has to be a capital `C` because C# is case-sensitive.

Comment: @sigil Yes, C# is case-sensitive, but the type `char` is exactly the same as `System.Char`. So, both versions will work the same here (unlike e.g. in Java, where `char` and `Character` are different types).

Comment: I didn't know that, thanks for pointing that out.